# T-SQL select records for the month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `logD`, with a field named `date` (datefield type).  Format is "year-month-day" IE: 2011-04-11

If today's date is 2011-07-31, I want all the records for the month of July.  If today's date is 2011-02-14, I want all the records for the month of Feb and so on.

I am using SQL 2008 and reporting services to run a monthly report.

Comment: What have you tried?  We are here to help solve problems, not do your work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM logD
 WHERE YEAR(DATE) = YEAR(GetDate())
   AND MONTH(DATE)  = MONTH(GetDate())
```

Comment: You can do it so the query would use indexes

Answer (score 3):

If you have an Index on the column `DATE` then you can try this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM logD
WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),GETDATE(),112)+'01' AND DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),GETDATE(),112)+'01'))
```

But, man, it looks ugly...

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest the same thing. Spare yourself one DATEADD and rewrite it as `[date] >= {this month}+'-01' AND [date] < {next month}+'-01'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @firstOfMonth smalldatetime = dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate()),0);

SELECT * FROM logD
WHERE [date] > @firstOfMonth 
AND   [date] < dateadd(month,1,@firstOfMonth);
```